# How to build only submodules of a gradle parent module?

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I am desperately trying to build only submodules of a gradle module.
This is my current struture:

```
root
|_ foo
   |_egg
   |_nogg
|_ bar
   |_celona
```

When I run

```
gradle :foo:egg:build
```

It builds the submodule.
I want it to build all two submodules `egg` and `nogg`

I tried:

```
gradle :foo:build
```

But it only build foo (which has no sources)

```
gradle :foo:*:build
```

Is what I expected to do or

```
gradle :foo::build
```

However no luck in getting it to work. Any ideas? The documentation is not giving out a hint for the multiproject part.

Comment: Except for navigating to the `foo` folder and running `gradle build` from there, I am not aware of any way to do that from the cli. However, if you want, you can make the `foo` project depend on its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute all foo sub-project tasks by specifying full path to each task:

```
gradle :foo:egg:build :foo:nogg:build
```

Gradle accepts multiple tasks in command line parameters.